# How to rename the .wav file which is going to download using the below program?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook, pyaudio, youtube-dl

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'wav',
        'preferredquality': '192'
    }],
    'postprocessor_args': [
        '-ar', '16000'
    ],
    'prefer_ffmpeg': True,
    'keepvideo': True
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpjEwIceVIo'])
```

---

Output:

```
[youtube] JpjEwIceVIo: Downloading webpage
[download] Speech on Importance of Education in English for Higher Secondary students by Smile Please World-JpjEwIceVIo.webm has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of 1.69MiB
[ffmpeg] Destination: Speech on Importance of Education in English for Higher Secondary students by Smile Please World-JpjEwIceVIo.wav
```

---

I want to change the filename to ***audio1.wav*** instead of ***Speech on Importance of Education in English for Higher Secondary students by Smile Please World-JpjEwIceVIo.wav***.  Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add 'outtmpl' in ydl_opts. If you prefer, use a variable too:

```
name = 'audio1'

ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl':name+'.%(ext)s',
    ...
}
```